# Save image from URL and save as featured image - wordpress create posts function

Tags: php, wordpress

After finding some code on stack overflow, i've put together the following -

it gets data from a feed called artlogic.

I am wondering how to get the image from the image URL, download it and then store it as the featured image for that specific post.

I did find another script that says its how you save images but it did not work, did not get any errors or anything, so not sure if i just have placed it in the wrong place.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
function test_button_action()
{
  echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>'
    .'Art Logic Feed Imported.' . '</p></div>';
    
      $to_create_posts = true;

  $data = RemoteArtworks::LoadRemoteArtworks( $to_create_posts );
  
  
}  



if (!class_exists('RemoteArtwork')) :
    class RemoteArtwork
    {
        // original data
        public $raw;

        // public items
        public $title;
        public $artwork_html;
        public $id;

        public function __construct($dirty_data)
        {
            $this->parse_data($dirty_data);
        }

        /**
         * Clean the data, never expect good data
         */
        private function sanitize_remote_data($data_as_array)
        {
            foreach ($data_as_array as $inx => $data) {
                $data_as_array [$inx] = sanitize_text_field($data);
            }
            return $data_as_array;
        }

        /**
         *  Take the dirty data, clean it, then set our properties
         */
        private function parse_data($dirty_data_as_array)
        {
            $clean_data = $this->sanitize_remote_data($dirty_data_as_array);

            // save the raw data (cleaned)
            $this->raw = $clean_data;

            // grab the values we need
            $this->title = $this->raw ['_title'];
            $this->artwork_html = $this->raw ['artwork_html'];
            $this->id = $this->raw ['id'];
        }

        /**
         * Update a post with the latest meta data
         */
        public function update_artwork_post_meta($post_id)
        {
            $meta_values_to_set = array (
            
                'image_url' => $this->raw['img_url']
            );

            foreach($meta_values_to_set as $key => $meta_value){
                $success = $this->update_meta($post_id, $key, $meta_value );
            }
        }

        public function update_meta ( $post_id, $key, $meta_value ){
            if ( isset( $meta_value ) && 0 < strlen( trim( $meta_value ) ) ) {
                return update_post_meta ( $post_id, $key, $meta_value );
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function get_meta ( $post_id, $key ){
            $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, true );
            return empty( $value ) ? null : $meta_value;
        }

    } // RemoteArtwork
endif; // RemoteArtwork


if (!class_exists('RemoteArtworks')) :
    class RemoteArtworks
    {
        /** data from url */
        public static $remote_data;

        /** parsed data -- use these instances for stuffs */
        public static $artworks;

        /**
         * Pull the main feed & extra pages
         */
        private static function GetRemoteArtworks($url)
        {
            // remote data
            $response = wp_remote_get($url);

            if (is_wp_error($response) || !isset($response['body'])) return; // bad response

            // the good stuff
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

            if (is_wp_error($body)) return; // bad body

            // decode the data
            $data = json_decode($body, true);

            if (!$data || empty($data)) return; // bad data

            // make sure there isn't anymore
            if (isset($data['page']) && isset($data['no_of_pages'])) {
                $page = $data['page'];
                $pages = $data['no_of_pages'];
                $next_page_link = $data['next_page_link'];
                if ($page !== $pages) {
                    // keep loading data from $next_page_link.....
                }
            }

            // final remote data
            return $data;
        }

        /**
         * Load the remote feed and parse the data
         */
        public static function LoadRemoteArtworks($to_create_posts)
        {
            self::$remote_data = self::GetRemoteArtworks('https://feeds.artlogic.net/farhifineart/websites/2.0/artworks/json/');

            if (!isset(self::$remote_data ['rows'])) return; // no rows --- booo!

            $works = array();
            foreach (self::$remote_data ['rows'] as $inx => $remote_item_data) {
                // create artwork instance
                $artwork = new RemoteArtwork($remote_item_data);
                $works[] = $artwork;
            }

            // set our local data that has been cleaned and parsed
            self::$artworks = $works;

            // let's make new POSTS!!!
            if ($to_create_posts) {
                $count = 0;
                foreach (self::$artworks as $inx => $artwork) {
                    $count++; // for demo ---- let's not go overboard here

                    $post_id = self::CreateLocalArtworkPost($artwork);

                    if ($post_id == -1) {
                        // Nothing happened
                    } else if ($post_id == -2) {
                        // already exists
                        // ... I guess we could update a post's data here...
                    } else {
                        // new post was created, let's update it's meta
                        $success = $artwork->update_artwork_post_meta($post_id);
                    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ($count >= 90) return self::$remote_data; ///////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////// FOR DEMO... DON'T DO EVERY POST
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////// BUT YOU COULD...
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
            }

            // return the remote data... for whatever reason outsite of this class
            return self::$remote_data;
        }

        public static function CreateLocalArtworkPost($artwork)
        {
            if (!$artwork) return -1;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DEBUG
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r( $artwork );
// echo '</pre>';
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // do post creation from $artwork data that has been sanitized

            $template = ''; // add a custom template if you want

            $post_type = 'artwork';

            $img_url = $artwork->raw['img_url'];
            
            $artwork_html = $artwork->artwork_html;

            $content = "<p>${artwork_html}</p>\n\r<br />\r\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"${img_url}\"><img width=\"100%\" height=\"auto\" src=\"${img_url}\"></a>";

            $new_post_id = self::CreateNewArtworkPost($post_type, $artwork->title, $content, $template, $artwork);

            return $new_post_id;
        
           

        }

        /**
         * orginal from - https://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/
         */
        public static function CreateNewArtworkPost($post_type = 'post', $title, $content, $template_rel_path = '', $data)
        {
            // Initialize the page ID to -1. This indicates no action has been taken.
            $post_id = -1;

            if (!current_user_can('publish_posts')) {
                // sorry...
                return $post_id;
            }

            // Prep
            $author_id = get_current_user_id();
            if (!$author_id) {
                return $post_id;
            }

            $title = sanitize_text_field(wp_strip_all_tags($title)); // remove any junk
            $title = esc_html(wp_unslash($title));
            $slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($title); // converts to a usable post_name
            $post_type = post_type_exists($post_type) ? $post_type : 'post'; // make sure it exists

            // If the page doesn't already exist, then create it (by title & slug)
            if (null == get_page_by_title($title) && empty(get_posts(array('name' => $slug)))) {



                // Set the post ID so that we know the post was created successfully
                $post_id = wp_insert_post(
                    array(
                        'post_name' => $slug,
                        'post_title' => $title,
                        'post_content' => $content,
                        'post_type' => $post_type,
                        'post_author' => $author_id,
                        'comment_status' => 'closed',
                        'ping_status' => 'closed',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                    )
                );
                




                if ($post_id && $post_id > 0 && !empty($template_rel_path)) {
                    
                  

                    // make sure the template exists
                    $template_full_path = trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()) . $template_rel_path;
                    if (file_exists($template_full_path)) {

                        // set the post meta data -- use relative path
                        update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', $template_rel_path);
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                } // end template check

                // Otherwise, we'll stop
            } else {
                // Arbitrarily use -2 to indicate that the page with the title already exists
                $post_id = -2;

            } // end if

            return $post_id;

        } // end programmatically_create_post

    }// RemoteArtworks
endif; // RemoteArtworks
```